# How to find Student which has name "John" and exam.name "Mathematica"?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have Student and Exam model in mongoose like

```
// Exam Schema
var ExamSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    mark: String,
    teacher: String,
    activated: Date
});

// Student Schema
var StudentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    exams: [ExamSchema],
    activated: Date
});
```

How to find Student which has name "John" and exam.name "Mathematica"?
I can do with find {'name': 'John'} but how to query when I have array and field.

Comment: I think you can just use `{"name": "John", "exams.name", "Mathematica"}`

Comment: What is array and field?